# Circular image as a button in html

Tags: html

I was just wondering if I could make a circular image (transparent PNG), that only activates when you click the non-transparent part of it. Thanks in advance.
My code right now:

```css
img {
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/98/Green_circle_filled.png" alt="circular image" onclick="alert('you can click anywhere in the border')">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can set `border-radius: 1000px` which would work if the image were a perfect square, however the image you are using is a rectangle so you would need to crop it first.

Comment: You can do this with a SVG https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uf84L6av/

Comment: If you are perfectly square, you should be using `border-radius:50%;` as a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, No. What you desire is currently impossible with your current setup. If you'd like to restrict click events to the circle only, you have to first crop the image to have equal width and height, and then apply

```css
border-radius: 50%;
```

This will ensure that the `img` element itself only takes up the same amount of space as the circle instead of just "containing a circle" (which is what your image does).

Although, this is the less preferred way. A better way would be to create an element that **is** a circle.

```css
.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div> /* This the container */
  <div class="circle" onclick="alert('You have clicked on the circle')"></div>
</div>
```

### This has a number of benefits:

- Your code is more readable
- The functionality doesn't depend on a link to work (in this case, the Wikimedia link)
- You may nest elements inside the circle as opposed to the image which is a self-closing element

An alternative would be to use and SVG as @j08691 suggested, but this would do exactly the same thing.